# ASANA Create Task API call stopped working

Tags: asana-api

In the last couple of weeks, Create Task API Call for ASANA stopped working. 
This code has been working for last 6 months but now it fails.
The error I get is 
The remote server returned an error: (434) Client Error (434).
According to the ASANA website
https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors
434 means Deprecated
but I am not sure what is Deprecated.
Does anybody have any suggestions I can try to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Since the API key is deprecated. This call was failing. I followed instructions on this page to fix it. https://asana.com/developers/feed/api-key-deprecation

Answer (score 0):

API Key is deprecated.
Use this page to change it: https://asana.com/developers/feed/api-key-deprecation